# Cómo saber cuantos caracteres tiene una palabra que está dentro de un texto

Tags: javascript

Const texto = "Hola mi nombre es emilio y tengo 30 años";

//Necesito saber la cantidad de caracteres que tiene emilio

Comment: `console.log("emilio".length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usando [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) e [indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof)

```js
const texto = "Hola mi nombre es emilio y tengo 30 años";
nombre = texto.substring(
  "Hola mi nombre es ".length,
  texto.indexOf(" y tengo")
);
console.log(nombre, nombre.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consulta información en google sobre la propiedad `length` de `javascript`.

```js
const texto = "Hola mi nombre es emilio y tengo 30 años";

console.log(texto.length);
```

[Más información en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)